# Client Side Validation fails when moving to viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This seems to a common question for lots of reasons that do not *seem* to apply to this situation.  I have create page using ASP.NET MVC 2 and I was using a strongly typed view to a class generated from DataEnities framework.

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"     Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MVC_EDI.Models.wysCustomerEndPoint>"" %>
```

I made validation class that I bound back to the the data class.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EndPointValidation))]
public partial class wysCustomerEndPoint
{        
}

[Bind()]
public class EndPointValidation
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the end point name")]
    public string CustName { get; set; }
```

And I was able to use client side validation on my create page.  I had a requirement to add a dropdown list box on the create page, so I switched my view to use a viewmodel instead of the data class I was using.

```
 public class CreateEditCustomerEndPointsViewModel
{
    public wysCustomerEndPoint CustomerEndPoint {get; set;}
    public List<SelectListItem> DefaultLocationList { get; set; } 
}
```

and here is the view header using the new viewmodel.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MVC_EDI.ViewModles.CreateEditCustomerEndPointsViewModel>" %>
```

But now when this view gets loaded I am getting an error that my formElement is null when it tries to set a value ?  I error out here inteh MicrosofyMvcValidation.js file and the formElement array is null.

```
formElement['__MVC_FormValidation'] = this
```

I suspect I need to add some sort of data annotation or attribute to either my view model or something like that.  But I am not sure where? And surprisingly it seems to work out just fine in FireFox 5 but bombs in IE9?

Edit: thanks for the reply. Yes I believe I am instantiating the object before adding to the ViewModel and using the Html.Helper objects?  Here is the code.

```
 wysCustomerEndPoint ep = new wysCustomerEndPoint();
 ep.BuyerID = id;
 var viewModel = new CreateEditCustomerEndPointsViewModel()
 {
    CustomerEndPoint = ep
 };
 return View(viewModel);
```

and in the view

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.Label("Name") %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerEndPoint.CustName) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerEndPoint.CustName) %>
</div>
```

cheers

bob

Comment: Do you check for model.isvalid? View models work slightly different i agree, however i noticed forcing this check on form post threw up errors...

Comment: No I did not.  When would I check that?  before send up the view,because the view will not even load.

Comment: I just broke out all the properties of wysCustomerEndPoint and placed them in the view model and map back and forth between the view model and wysCustomerEndPoint.  Seems kind of cheesy to me, but it works. thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Its cool... Fyi you would check as soon as form is posted and before any service or mapping is initiated, i.e. The very first thing on the form post controller action. So yes way before sending to view... I assume the process would be 1. form post, 2. model.isvalid check, if valid do mapping or invoke some service or whatever you do 3. redirect lf sucess else send out view with data and errors inside the model state. You can check when debugging if there are any errors present in model state...

Answer (score 0):

You're maybe doing this, but without seeing the relevant bits of code I don't want to assume. So, make sure you are instantiating the wysCustomerEndPoint object and sending to your view from the Controller method. Also that you are using the Html Helpers for the input elements that you are validating on. Eg.

```
Html.TextboxFor(model => model.wysCustomerEndPoint.CustName)
```